# union size is not taking highest size of data type?

Tags: c, sizeof, unions

union size is not taking highest size of of its element  ?It is taking 12 byte not 10 byte but if i remove float in the below code than it will take 10 byte can any one explain it please ?

```
 union u
 {
  char ch[10];
  //float f; 
 };
   int main()
  {
      union u var;
      printf("%d\n",sizeof(var));  // why size is 12 here why not 10 but if float is removed then size is 10 please explain?
   }
```

Comment: it sounds to have something to do with alignment.

Comment: Search alignment and padding-related questions here on SO. They pop up very often here.

Answer (score 0):

It's all implementation dependant, and to do with allignment and padding *etc*.  Use a different comiler/version/system and it'll probably be totally different.